# Eclipse console exception color

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, colors, preferences

This seems simple enough, but I can't seem to find the setting in Eclipse to change this setting.

I prefer my consoles to have dark colors with white text.  I leave the print to stderr as the red default.

My problem lies in when I receive an Exception, it's set to a very dark blue, so I can't see the text of it easily without highlighting the link.

I didn't see it in the console preferences, and also do not see it anywhere in the various other setting locations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Changing the **Hyperlink text color** will do what you want, but this is used elsewhere in Eclipse so you may want to choose a colour that is reasonably legible on both light and dark backgrounds.

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Does `Hyperlink text color` do the trick?

Comment: ...Which can be found in "Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts->Hyperlink text color".

Answer (score 1):

"General"->"Appearance"->"Colors and Fonts", "Hyperlink text Color"?

Answer (score 1):

I like this:

[Console Grep](http://marian.musgit.com/projects_grepconsole.php)

It allows for custom highlighting/text colors depending on what is printed. Assuming you have an idea of how regexes work (if not lots of tutorials exist) it works quite well.